# PyAutoGUI not recognizing open application on screen

Tags: python, virtualbox, pyautogui

I'm running a Windows application and trying to locate buttons on the screen but PyAutoGUI is not recognizing the application. It will not locate the button image and when I try to screenshot the location where the button is, it captures the desktop. Or if there is a second application hidden behind the active application, it will capture that screen. It's as if the application is no on the screen.

This is all in a VirtualBox machine. The interesting thing is that this VM is a clone of a Parallels machine where everything works fine. If I try to locate other images such as the application icon on the desktop, everything works fine so I'm kind of stumped as to what is going on here.

Comment: You should add enough details to your question that the problem can be replicated. Also what makes you think it is a problem with your (unprovided) code and not with the application or the VM?

Comment: I didn't necessarily think it was a problem with the code but didn't want to rule it out. It turns out the issue is that there are some guest additions that don't get installed when you install the default guest additions in VirtualBox. You need to have 3D Acceleration enabled in Windows in order for some applications to be capturable.